# Configuring Terminal on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I installed Node.js via the precompiled package but I can't access it correctly via the Terminal.

```
> node
```

does not work instead I have to type:

```
> sudo /usr/local/bin/node
```

My `$PATH` reads:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

What do I need to configure?

I am running OSX 10.10 (14A299l) (XCode6 Beta 4 is installed)

Comment: Just make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH. You probably want to set this in your `~/bashrc` file, e.g. just add "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

Comment: as you can see in my Question /usr/local/bin is already in my $PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compiled this package as root it is likely that the file structure all has root ownership. What do you see when you type,

```
 ls -l /usr/local/bin/
```

If the node.js folder says something like root:root before it then you need to change the permissions via

```
chmod -R user:user /usr/local/bin/node....
```

Comment: Yosemite apparently defaults to 'No access' for everyone for the folder /usr/local/bin.